# debian becomes slow after connecting a camera

Tags: debian

my debian becomes slow after connecting a camera
i use gnome 3
512mb ram
3 GHz Pentium dual processor
256 MB graphics.

please help.
it hangs and does not respond

Comment: It's possibly a driver bug spinning the kernel. If you can get this to stop without rebooting, print the output from `dmesg | tail -n 30`.  If not, just kill the power and wait a few minutes, then reboot.  That pause should make it easier to go back through `/var/log/syslog` to the point before the reboot; rebooting will have added a lot to the log, but it will all be within a few seconds.  You can also look for a line with `[    0.000000] Linux version`; that will be near the beginning.  You want to cut n' paste the errors from *before* the reboot.

Comment: http://freetexthost.com/nikdwifda3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the camera driver -- it's the video driver when the camera is plugged in:

```
[ 4549.630739] usb 1-6: Product: Canon Digital Camera
[ 4549.630743] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Canon Inc.
[ 4549.630746] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: A2852D54A0214DB49ACA0A715FB45D48
[ 5993.868023] [drm:i915_hangcheck_ring_idle] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... render ring idle [waiting on 1011506, at 1011506], missed IRQ?
```

There's a 25 minute (1500 second) gap between registering the camera and the reported hangcheck error -- presumably the system was locked up during this time.

But the hangcheck is reported from the i915 drm ("direct rendering management") module.  The i915 is a driver for Intel integrated graphics.

I have a system with onboard Intel graphics using the i915 driver and it is buggy; I and others have [reported this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58381), and a patch was apparently written.  I can't say whether the patch works because my problems stopped with kernel 3.11.

If you can manage to get a 3.11+ kernel from some debian repo (it won't be in the default ones), then you could try that.  If not, you can build and install one [from source](https://www.kernel.org/).